# Namespace merge in .d.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

#### Another document(.d.ts)(try)

```
import Kvl from 'kvl';

declare namespace kvl {
    interface test1{

    }
}
//error
```

### a total document(.d.ts)

```
declare class kvl {}

declare namespace kvl{
    interface Request {}
    interface Response {

    }
}
export as namespace kvl;
export default kvl;
```

### Another document(.d.ts)

```
import Kvl from 'kvl';

declare module "kvl" {

    namespace kvl {
        interface test1{

        }
    }
}
```

### Project code

```
import kvl from 'kvl';
const name: kvl.test1;
```

kvl.test1[error]

I want to add a method to the namespace inside .d.ts, but my addition failed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

```
declare class kvl {

}

declare global{
    namespace kvl{
        interface Request {}
        interface Response {}
    }

}



export as namespace kvl;
export default kvl;
```